# Which quantity is minimized in energy balance models

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, equilibrium, differential-equations

In [zero-dimensional energy balance models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_model#Zero-dimensional_models) (EBM) of the atmosphere one may consider in the most simple case the differential equation

$$k\,dT/dt = \alpha - \beta T^4$$

with [heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity) $k$ of unit $[k]=1\,J/K$, so $[\alpha] = 1\,W$ and $[\beta]=1\,W/K^4$. The equation thus relates [power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(physics))-like quantities.

One finds equilibrium points with $dT/dt = 0$ for

$$T = (\alpha/\beta)^{1/4}$$

Two of them are imaginary, one is negative, so only one remains as physically plausible.

In classical mechanics we have (roughly speaking)

$$m\,d^2x/dt^2 = - dE/dx$$

for some $x$-dependent energy $E(x)$ and inertial mass $m$. So it might be natural to consider - as an analogy - the $T$-dependent quantity $X(T)$ such that

$$k\,dT/dt = - dX/dT$$

that means

$$X(T) = \frac{\beta}{5}T^5 - \alpha T$$

Like energy $E$ in classical mechanics, in EBMs the quantity $X$ is minimized. But what does it mean? Its unit is $[X] = 1\,WK$.

We can write

$$X(T) = (\frac{\beta}{5}T^4 - \alpha)\text{sec} \cdot T/\text{sec}$$

and so one interpretation of the quantity $X$ might be:

> $X(T)$ is the **product** of some net energy emitted (**in** one second)
> and some temperature (change?) **per** second.

My questions are:

> - Which physcial quantities are there that are the product of an energy and a rate? Which role do they play?
> - Because of the factor $5$ the energies $(\beta T^4 - \alpha)\text{sec}$ and $(\beta T^4 / 5- \alpha)\text{sec}$ are not the
>   same. The first is the net energy emitted in one second, but what is the other?

Comment: Your $X$ has units of temperature squared over time. Can you elaborate on the sense in which it is an energy "up to a factor". I am also not clear what you mean by saying $\alpha T$ is a measure of the "heat energy of the atmosphere". $\alpha t$ would be a measure of the cumulative heat absorbed by the earth but I cannot see an obvious interpretation of $\alpha T$

Comment: @BySymmetry: Thanks for your questions. I reworked my question which was ill-posed. Does it make sense now?

Comment: In the first equation, it is balance between energy absorption rate $\alpha$ and energy dissipation rate (stefan-Botlzmann), the second term is a function of temperature. What is the advantage to invent an integral function of the net rate?

Comment: @ytlu: What was the advantage to invent Lagrangians, Hamiltonians, and so on?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker They are advantages, special in dealing with constrain force which are not easy to describe explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

What is missing in the analogy with the mechanical model is that the latter is described by a second-order equation, whereas the equation of interest is a first-order equation, more suggestive of diffusion dynamics (which is actually what one would expect for heat flows, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation)).

However, if we decide to use this analogy, we could draw paralleles with dynamics of an overdamped particle, described by a Langevin equation:
$$
m\ddot{x}=-m\gamma\dot{x}-\frac{dU(x)}{dx} + f(t),
$$
(where $f(t)$ is a random force which is not essential for the discussion, but which I included for completeness.)
This equation can be written as a system of the first order differential equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}=v,\\
\dot{v} = -\gamma v-\frac{1}{m}\frac{dU(x)}{dx}+\frac{1}{m}f(t)
\end{cases}
$$
The *overdamped approximation* consist in assuming that $\gamma$ is very big, so that velocity quickly decays, and we can set $\dot{v}=0$, so that the second equation results in
$$
v\approx -\frac{1}{m\gamma}\frac{dU(x)}{dx}+\frac{1}{m\gamma}f(t),
$$
which, when plugged into the first equation, gives us
$$
\dot{x}= -\frac{1}{m\gamma}\frac{dU(x)}{dx}+\frac{1}{m\gamma}f(t),
$$

If we now compare this with the temperature equation in the OP, we could write
$$
\frac{dT}{dt}=-\frac{d}{dT}\left[\frac{1}{m\gamma}U(T)\right],\\
\frac{1}{m\gamma}U(T)=\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{\beta T^5}{5} -\alpha T\right)
$$
What is identified as coefficient $m\gamma$ is somewhat arbitrary. One could, e.g., choose it in such a way that $U(T)$ is measured in energy units or temperature units.

What is more interesting here is that $U(T)$ can be now viewed as a potential, whereas the temperature is a particle in this potential, which relaxes to its minimum at $T=(\alpha/\beta)^{1/4}$ - this allows to use whatever mechanical intuition one has from real life. More precisely, the potential is
$$
\frac{m\gamma}U(T)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{\beta T^5}{5} -\alpha T\right), T\geq 0,\\
+\infty, T<0
\end{cases},
$$
since the negative temperatures are not allowed.

More generally in such models one includes a random force $f(t)$, which drives the particle out of equilibrium state, so that one can obtaine a probability distribution around this state, see [this review](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.62.251) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for making explicit my assumptions, Roger. I've been aware that the analogy was not quite sound (and that considering overdamping would have been needed), but finally you come up with the same "potential" as I did, and with temperature being a "particle" in this potential. But my question has been: How do I interpret this potential, what kind of physical quantity is it? What kind of [thermodynamic potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_potential) is it - if any?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker You can readily exclude all the thermodynamic potentials that do not have temperature as an independent variable. The rest depends on the details - whether teh situation is characterized by constant pressure, whether there is exchange of particles, etc.

Comment: How would I characterize the situation of interest in climate EBMs - modelling the temperature of the atmosphere? Constant pressure (because the atmosphere can expand freely)?

Comment: I am null in climate science. The linked article talks about zero-dimensional models, so I would think of a closed box with gas. This is not realistic, as the atmosphere can expand, if its temperature grows, or even lose particles to the space - but then you need a more complex model.